# Sub figure number doesn't show with polyglossia

Tags: subfloats, polyglossia

I'm trying to put 4 figures side by side
I'm using the code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage{subfigure}


% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subfigure[Caption of subfigure 1]{
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}
    \label{fig:subfig1}
}
\subfigure[Caption of subfigure 2]{
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}
    \label{fig:subfig2}
}
\subfigure[Caption of subfigure 3]{
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}
    \label{fig:subfig3}
}
\subfigure[Caption of subfigure 4]{
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}
    \label{fig:subfig4}
}
\caption[Optional caption for list of figures]{Caption of subfigures \subref{fig:subfig1}, \subref{fig:subfig2} and \subref{fig:subfig3}}
\label{fig:subfigureExample}
\end{figure}
Reference to figure \ref{fig:subfigureExample}.

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
all things go wright till I add the code 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals = maghrib, calendar = locale]{arabic}%maghrib
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Amiri} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Amiri}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

to use arabic language in the document
the numbers (a,b,c,d) of the subfigures doesn't show
I'm using texlive with xelatex to compile the document

```
%%%%Before adding polyglossia
```

[image]

```
%%%%After Adding polyglossia
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: This is worked fine ... Thanx

Comment: one more question please... Can I replace (ا-ب-ج-د) numbering with (a-b-c-d) in the same document?

Answer (score 1):

The `subfigure` package has been obsolete for 15 years or so. Use `subfig` or the more modern `subcaption`. The former requires just changing `\subfigure` into `\subfloat`.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals = maghrib, calendar = locale]{arabic}%maghrib
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Amiri} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Amiri}
\setotherlanguage{english}



% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subfloat[Caption of subfigure 1]{
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}
    \label{fig:subfig1}
}
\subfloat[Caption of subfigure 2]{
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}
    \label{fig:subfig2}
}

\subfloat[Caption of subfigure 3]{
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}
    \label{fig:subfig3}
}
\subfloat[Caption of subfigure 4]{
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}
    \label{fig:subfig4}
}
\caption[Optional caption for list of figures]
  {Caption of subfigures \subref{fig:subfig1},
   \subref{fig:subfig2} and \subref{fig:subfig3}}
\label{fig:subfigureExample}
\end{figure}
Reference to figure \ref{fig:subfigureExample}.

\end{document}
```

[image]